# vowpal wabbit install: completes with no errors but vw doesn't work

Tags: installation, ubuntu-12.04, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to install vowpal wabbit on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I followed the directions on this [page](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial), which I summarize here:

```
git clone git://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git

cd vowpal_wabbit

make

make test
```

All completes with no errors. But when I try

```
vw
```

or

```
vw --help
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/vw: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty new to linux and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to install the vw binary into `/usr/local/bin/vw` using

```
sudo make install
```

Another solution is to create an alias to the vw binary:

```
alias vw=/path/where/I/have/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/vw
```

Yet another solution would be to create a symlink to the binary from a directory in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Please note that the alias solution would work only in the present shell.  A better and cleaner solution would be to add the directory where `vw` is installed to `PATH`.  This will ensure that it is found by other programs called from the shell. Explicit syntax would be: `export PATH=$PATH:/directory/where/vw/is/installed`

Comment: If a permanent change is needed, both `alias...` and `export PATH...` commands must be run when a new shell starts, which can be done e.g. in `~/.bashrc` (if you use Bash). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917942/advantage-of-path-over-alias

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install VW is to get its compiled version from official repository.

```
sudo apt-get install vowpal-wabbit
```

Update by [Alesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4684809/alesh): However, the compiled version of VW is not the most updated version. At the moment the complied version is 7.3, while at git the current version is 7.10.